# Can I add more than 300 columns in Apache Kudu?

Tags: apache-kudu

I have been asked to create a Kudu table.

I know that Kudu is a columnar storage, but now my company's database table has like 285 columns which can fit in the the Kudu table, but is it possible to dynamically add columns in excess of the 300 column limit in a Kudu table? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@HJSG
Kudu give's best performance with < 300 COLUMNS and Kudu Tables can have a maximum of 300 columns. it is a Kudu limitation. have a look into this https://kudu.apache.org/docs/known_issues.html#_columns

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what happens if exceeding 300 cols limit, but here you are:
--unlock-unsafe-flags --max-num-columns=1000

[Ref](https://books.google.com.vn/books?id=teZfDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA12&lpg=PA12&dq=what%20if%20I%20need%20more%20than%20300%20columns%20kudu&source=bl&ots=sm-62h7j8W&sig=NZpe-tXe9qzbSaS5oxqoNGfmsVM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjNqLWo8KLcAhUKU30KHYqzAOgQ6AEIajAL#v=onepage&q=what%20if%20I%20need%20more%20than%20300%20columns%20kudu&f=false)